# Issue with first time usage of Segment on react app

Tags: reactjs, segment

### I have created a codesandbox to show my misunderstanding:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-cerf-00p01t

As you can see in the console of this codeSandbox example, printing the value of window.analytics returns an array with two strings instead of an object with all the segment functions I am supposed to use.

Looks like I should wait some milliseconds for the library to be ready.
This is not shown on the official docs.
we Would love to know how a basic usage of react and Segment should work.